# inserting multiple values into a single cell

Tags: sql

i am trying to insert multiple values into a single cell column in my db. i am using a sql statment like this:

```
insert into table_name (mycol) values (1A,2B,3G,4,5,6F)
```

this table has only one field called "mycol"

the above query doesn't run and gives me an error. however, if i run it single entry like this:
insert into table_name (mycol) values (1A)
it works!

is there a way to feed sql with multiple values?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? BTW, databases don't have cells. They have tables, with rows and columns.

Comment: What is the datatype of mycol?

Comment: @Tom; What abour records, fields, tuples, etc.  It's all just symantics.  As long as we understand each other, it's not like we'll confuse 'cell' with some other relational entity...

Comment: it is one single column and a 5 decimal with no null values.

Comment: Have you tried the `UNION ALL` versions listed below?

Comment: @Dems - Without getting into a long discussion in comments... it matters because how people new to a technology talk about it influences how they think about it. Someone unfamiliar with database concepts who thinks of a database as a giant Excel spreadsheet will never learn to think in a set-based way. While you may have enough experience not to confuse things, someone new to databases doesn't have that same experience and will confuse things.

Comment: I found a way around this. I selected from a table and then inserted it and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You have to break up the values portion like so (if you're using SQL Server)

```
insert into table_name (mycol) values (1A),(2B),(3G),(4),(5),(6F)
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. Yes I am using SQL server. when i run my original query i get this error: "number of inserted values is not the same as the number of object columns"

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? Because I just ran this query on SQL Server 2008 and it ran w/o incident.  I believe it works in 05, but not 100% sure on that one.

Comment: Works for me once I add single quotes around the values, cool tip!

Comment: My bad... it's been quite a while since I did '05 work so I couldn't remember.

Comment: i have older version of sql server. i think this is as close as it can work. i guess i will just have to insert 1k values line by line.

Comment: I found a way around this. I selected from a table and then inserted it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[Based on this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/), you can do something like this:

```
USE YourDB
GO
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend *against* storing multiple values in a single field.  You're better off, normally, with having seperate fields *or* multiple rows...

If student X is on Courses A, B, C;

```
INSERT INTO mapping_table (student_id, course_id)
            SELECT 123, 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 3
```

If student X has 3 lines in his address;

```
INSERT INTO student_address (student_id, line1, line2, line3)
SELECT 123, '10 The Street', 'The Town', 'The City'
```

Comment: I took "several values" to mean "several rows for a single field at one time" given his sample data.  1A could be the Course Section, or Product ID.  It's not necessary that 1 is a product and A is a second product.

Comment: Possibly, I'm uncertain now that I've though the question's phrasing a bit more.  I thought the OP's question was the age old one about creating a comma seperated string of values to store in a single field of a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the selected values or do something like this:

```
INSERT dbo.Table_1(mycol)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT '1a' AS mycol UNION
SELECT '2b' UNION
SELECT '3g' UNION
SELECT '4' UNION
SELECT '5'
) T1
```

Comment: Be careful of `UNION` as it will de-dupe your data before inserting it.  Also, the nested query isn't needed, although not harmful.